# Where is imageio finding 'chelsea.png'

Tags: python, python-imageio

I'm working with imageio in Python and the sample code shows a variable "im" reading "chelsea.png" but that file doesn't exist on my machine anywhere.

```
import imageio as iio

im = iio.imread('imageio:chelsea.png')
print(im.shape)
```

The output is:

```
(200, 200, 3)
```

I'm assuming it's a 200x200 image.  My questions are why does this code work?

With regard to the output of ImageIO, what does the 3 refer to?

Answer (score 3):

- Why does it work? Because the `imageio:` url prefix is [magic](https://imageio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting_started/standardimages.html) and refers to a set of automatically downloaded images.
- What does the 3 mean? The number of colour channels (R, G, and B.)

Comment: How come you view the prefix as magic? Isn't it just a schema like `https:` or `ftp:`? (Which works just the same: `iio.imread("https://github.com/imageio/imageio-binaries/blob/master/images/chelsea.png?raw=true"`)

Comment: I suppose "magic" has no formal definition. :-) What I meant was, that unlike e.g. https:, where you explicitly name the location from where a resource can be fetched, with imageio: you just give it a filename and the library "knows" where to get it.